# Change position Product_Tittle Woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have a problem regarding the title position of some woocommerce products.
They are next to the image of my product and I would like to put it on the top of the image.

How can I do this?

```
<figcaption>
    <div class="shop-loop-product-info">
        <h3 class="product_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <?php if (dh_get_theme_option('woo-list-rating',1) =='1') :?>
            <div class="info-meta clearfix">
                <?php woocommerce_template_loop_rating(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>

        <div class="info-price">
            <?php woocommerce_template_loop_price(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php DH_Woocommerce::countdown_html()?>
        <div class="info-excerpt">
            <?php echo wp_trim_words($post->post_excerpt,apply_filters('dh_woocommerce_list_mode_excerpt_lenght', 30))?>
        </div>
        <div class="list-info-meta clearfix">
            <div class="list-action clearfix">
                <div class="loop-add-to-cart">
                    <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart();?>
                </div>
                <?php 
                    if(class_exists('DH_Woocommerce'))
                    DH_Woocommerce::instance()->template_loop_quickview();
                ?>
                <?php if(class_exists('DH_Woocommerce')):?>
                    <div class="loop-add-to-wishlist">
                        <?php DH_Woocommerce::instance()->template_loop_wishlist()?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</figcaption>
```

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that **you are using some custom code,** so not sure that **this will work for you**.

To move the product title before the product image on archive pages as shop, use the following:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 9 );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: It's true it did not work, this theme I'm using is pretty crazy if it's called luxury wp

Comment: @RamonMatias You need to look in the woocommerce folder inside the theme where the customized woocommerce templates are located… That is the only way to find out the way.

Comment: I know this is an old question, and in this case I understand its necessary to modify the template with the actions. But whats the performance difference from using plain css to achieve similar results (etc swapping position of price and rating)?

Answer (score 0):

You can move any actions by just removing them and adding them to another location. Code bellow removes the title from side of the image to above the block. You can paste it in your theme's functions.php file:

```
//repostion single product title
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 10 );
```

Since you have a custom template, it could work only with 2nd line alone.

Comment: It did not work out, this theme I'm using is pretty crazy